# CompletableFuture all of to run 3 task asynchronously

Tags: spring, spring-boot, completable-future

In my application we are saving data to tables and ES inside Transaction block

- table A (Internal using OneToMany)
- table B
- Elastic search

As above 3 are independent operations i want to use CompletableFuture.allOf() but unable to find correct examples on this.

**Note:** I cant compromise transnational behavior and looking to increase performance to run all above 3 asynchronously. Expecting Boolean in return to make sure operation was successful before returning 201

Answer (score 0):

> The allOf factory method takes as input an array of CompletableFutures and >returns a CompletableFuture that’s completed only when all the >CompletableFutures passed have completed.

The above is mentioned in 'Java 8 in Action' by Raoul-Gabriel Urma, Mario Fusco, and Alan Mycroft.

You create an array of CompletableFutures and supply to allOf factory method. This will complete only when all of completableFuture completes.

For your use case, thenCombine operator is best suited as this can combine two CompletableFutures asynchronously without waiting for one another to complete. After you get response from both CompletableFutures, you can decide how to combine these two in thenCombine operator.
For example,

> CompletableFuture tableAFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dao.insert(tableA));
> CompletableFuture tableBFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dao.insert(tableB));
>
> CompletableFuture combinedFuture = tableAFuture.thenCombine(tableBFuture, (tableAFuture, TableBFuture) -> tableAFuture && tableBFuture)

Similary, you can define another CompletableFuture for task of saving in Elastic Search and combine it with combinedFuture. Therefore all your completableFuture will be working asynchronously.

If you want to understand operators of CompletableFuture and other features of Java 8, 'Java 8 in Action' is a good read (Link given below)
https://www.amazon.in/Java-Action-Lambdas-functional-style-programming/dp/1617291994/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1511971412&sr=8-1&keywords=java+8+in+action+lambdas%2C+streams%2C+and+functional-style+programming

Comment: i am aware of this approach but was wondering if i can run all three in parallel.  looks like we dont have much choice with CompletableFuture and have to do it in old way.